# Percentage of Data Above Median Line Based on Category

Tags: powerbi, dax, field

I am happy to share my full data set and full dashboard if someone can tell me how to do that. for now I'll post pictures.

Info: OVR Median is the Overall median of my full data set. the full data set is bigger than what is shown here.

Info: Table_1 and Table_2 have a relationship with the "Date" Fields.

I want to make a card like this one for my current data set

[image]

This card is from a different dashboard. I had to use DAX to make the card, but this was a while ago and I do not know how to replicate this within my current data set

This is my current dashboard below. There are 2 categories for the data. Category 1 is "FOMC Meetings", and Category 2 is "Earnings."

I would like to take to make a card like this.

Range Above OVR Median for FOMC Meeting Dates

(Divided by)

Count Range for FOMC Meeting Dates

I want the result to show me a big Card that reads

85% FOMC Meeting dates are above OVR Median

or 7/8 FOMC Meeting dates are above OVR Median

[image]

again i am happy to provide all my dashboard and all my data if someone can  tell me how to do that. big thankyou in advance to anyone who helps.

Soooo i kind of already explained what i tried what i was expecting above so i dont know why theres an extra field for me to type this in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 measures like this:

```
Count Range for FOMC Meeting Dates =
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Table_1[Range] ), 'Table_2'[Category] = "FOMC" )

Range Above OVR Median for FOMC Meeting Dates =
CALCULATE ( [Count Range for FOMC Meeting Dates], Table_1[Range] > 7 )

Pct Over =
DIVIDE (
    [Range Above OVR Median for FOMC Meeting Dates],
    [Count Range for FOMC Meeting Dates]
)
```

if the Median OVR is a calculation, that could replace `7` in the range above measure

Comment: That worked great. I was able to use this for both the FOMC meeting category and the earnings category, thankyou.